# Total number of particular data

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have 2 sheets, Herein sheet1 are items that an employee has, and I want to organize it in sheet 2 by adding all items that particular employee has.

Can someone help me, please?

Example. In sheet 1 Employee mark have multiple items, in sheet 2 I want to total all the items that Employeemark has.

Sheet 1

```
*---*----*---*----*----*
|   | ITEMS  | Employee|
*---*--------*----*----*
| 1 | BOOK    | MARK   |
| 2 | PEN     | MARK   |
| 3 | tape    | MARK   |
| 4 | BOOK    | MARK   |
| 5 | PEN     | GIL    |
| 6 | TAPE    | GIL    |
| 7 | BAG     | JANE   |
| 8 | PEN     | JANE   |
*---*----*--------*----*
```

Sheet 2

```
*---*----*---*-----*------*------*------*
|   |Employee| PEN | BOOK | TAPE | BAG  |
*---*--------*-----*------*------*------*
| 1 | Mark   |  1  |  2   |  1   |      |
| 2 | GIL    |  1  |      |  1   |      |
| 3 | JANE   |  1  |      |      |   1  |
*---*--------*-----*------*------*------*
```

This is the formula I'm using, but no result.

```
=iferror(QUERY('sheet1'!a1:b,"select a, count(b) where b = 'pencil|tape' group by a"),{"♥","♥","♥"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UPPER(B1:C), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sir @player0 , How about i add a column contains Quantity, instead of total all the items that Employee, it will total the Quantity of the items that employee has.